# Copy Paste loop through columns

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

- Loop through Row 1, from Column A to Column Z
- If cell of row 1 is greater than 0, Copy Row 1 cell, and paste it in Row 2.

Below is the code I am using.

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet3")

For x = A To Z
If ws.Range(x & "1").Value <> 0 Then
    ws.Range(x & "1").Copy
    ws.Range(x & "2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you talking about Excel? Or Excel Macros? If so it would be apt to add the appropriate tags to this question!

Comment: What is your problem? What language is this?

Comment: So, you're not actually *using* this code, because it won't compile.